# Traveling salesman problem with two salesmen

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science

Two salesmen travel around a city visiting all of the stores. Each store needs to be visited by exactly one salesman. How do I compute in Matlab the shortest total distance the salesmen need to travel? Is there a special algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could first find a solution to the normal TSP, and then split it into two routes. If AB and CD are edges in the normal TSP solution, then replacing those edges by AD and CB will give two separate loops. Just check every pair of edges to see which pair leads to the two loops with the shortest total length. I'm not sure this is guaranteed to always be the optimal two-salesmen solution, but it won't be far off.

Comment: Do the salesmen have to start at the same “depot” node, or do you want two node-disjoint subtours that together contain all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Surely this problem is at least as hard as the single traveling salesman (i.e NP-hard) so Matlab will not succeed except for very modest graph size. The usual approach to solving the single traveling salesman is to use dynamic programming, which runs in $O(2^n n)$ time (see e.g. the description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)). You can solve the two-salesman variant with only slight modification: once you have finished computing the shortest path length $L$ for a single salesman to visit all subsets of the stores $S$, compute
$$\min_{T\subset S}\ L(T) + L(S\setminus T).$$

Comment: Or, you could probably get a pretty good solution, though not technically optimal, by applying some heuristics for ways to improve a solution and then iterating until none of the heuristics find any improvements anymore.  (Though "scoring" isn't as obvious in this problem - for example, if you want to balance the work loads of the two salesmen, how much do you weight imbalance vs. total length of the cycles?)

Answer (score 0):

Though this problem is hard to solve in general, for most purposes you can solve it as an integer linear program. Mathworks even has an example on their website: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/travelling-salesman-problem.html